Does ArrayFire have a popcount or bitcount function?
I am trying to move away from OpenCL and CUDA into ArrayFire. One of my functions uses the GPU's popcount() to make pre-processing data easier. But I can't find it anywhere in the list of functions in ArrayFire.
OpenCL has popcount, CUDA has popc, and there is the builtin_popcount for CPU work. Where the heck is the function in ArrayFire? I see count() and count_all() but those are for the element count of the array not the bits in an element (as far as I can tell).
Am I missing something or is this just a feature not implemented in the library? I feel like it is a pretty important function and expected it to be with the bitwise manipulation functions.
I was expecting some function with the ability to tell me the count of 1s in an integer. I honestly would like to leverage the optimization features of the library, but without this it is impossible.
Yes, I can write my own. No I don't want to do it. I want to use the architecture optimized implementations provided by the hardware vendor on the CPUs/GPUs.

Well I will answer my own question.
There is not one.
I looked through the repo, yes they use popc and popcount (CUDA and OpenCl) for the nearest_neighbour. But it is not used anywhere else. So it is not implemented.
Now I have a few choices; use the custom kernel, fork their code and make my own, or abandon this folly and move on.
I will probably try the custom kernel. If it fails I will switch back to OpenCL and CUDA.
